# Link D3 force layout network diagram with table on mouseover

Tags: d3.js, highlight, force-layout

I took Michael Bostock's forced network example of a molecule, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3037015

[image]

I added a table of the data following the example in http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/add-html-table-to-your-d3js-graph.html.

I added separate mouseover events to the network and the table.  If I mouseover a node in the diagram, the selected node is highlighted in orange.

```
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")

            .on("mouseover", function() { 
                d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 6  ); 
                d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke", "orange"); 
                d3.select(this).select("text").style("font", "20px sans-serif");
                })
            .on("mouseout",  function() { 
                d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 1.5); 
                d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke", "gray"  ); 
                d3.select(this).select("text").style("font", "12px sans-serif");
                })
            .call(force.drag)
            ;
```

And if I mouseover a row in the table, the selected row is highlighted in orange.

```
            var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("tr")
                .on('mouseover', function(){d3.select(this).style('background-color', 'orange');})
                .on('mouseout',  function(){d3.select(this).style('background-color', 'white');})
                ;
```

I would like to link the mouseover highlighting of the diagram and the table such that:

- If I mouse over a node in the diagram, the selected node and its corresponding row in the table are both highlighted.
- If I mouse over a row in the table, the selected row and its corresponding node in the diagram are both highlighted.

I haven't been able to find an example of a mouseover-linked diagram and table in D3.  Can you point me to one?  Or suggest a solution?

I am using local copies of D3 (d3.v3.js) and the data (graph.json) and viewing the diagrams on Firefox 20.0.1 for Windows.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use dom element classes, selections and the data objects that your mouse events will have. Have a look at a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/UaWgH/)

The pertinent parts:

I am linking the rectangles to the circles based on a join between "class" and "cat" in their two respective datasets. To get at the elements quickly I will incorporate those items into the class attribute:

```
var table = svg.selectAll('rect').data(data).enter().append('rect');
table.attr(...)
     .attr('class', function(d) { return d["class"];} );
```

You can attach a class to any element, also you can attach more than one class to each element (it is considered a space-delimited list)

I do the same for each circle. Now in the circle mouseover I add:

```
balls.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    d3.select(this).attr("fill","#ffeeee");
    d3.selectAll("rect." + d.cat)
        .attr('stroke','red')
        .attr('stroke-width', 3);  
})
```

D3 passes the data object of the moused-over element, so I grab it's "cat" and use that with a D3 selector on rect's with that class. Like jQuery "rect.A" will select all "rect" elements with class "A"

For a different approach that uses brushes and selects ranges more than elements you can also check out [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) whose landing page has a great full example.

Comment: It was very helpful to see your working demo.  I created a class for my node with the name of the atom, `.attr("class", function(d) { return d.atom ;})`, and I referred to that class for the table mouseover, `d3.selectAll("circle" + d.class).style("stroke-width", 6);`, but it didn't work.  I'm new to D3 (and js) so I may be making an elementary mistake.  I created a jsfiddle that shows a working diagram and table, and a non-working link from the table mouseover to the diagram [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JVAdams/SDJjV/3/).

Comment: So a few things. If you look closely you will see that you node is actually a group that contains the circle and text - that is what you are setting the class on - you are also overriding the old class which is used in the node selection. So I would replace that with 
.attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.atom ;})

But the to get at the circle and the text you will have to adjust the selection. In the mouse handlers try using 
d3.selectAll("g." + d.atom + " circle")

Note that the "." and the " " are important. The period is to say you want a class, the space to find a child.

Comment: I replaced the `.attr("class"` bit and edited the mouse handlers as you suggested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JVAdams/SDJjV/4/).  The linking still isn't working.  Perhaps I need to specify `node` somewhere so that it knows I want the nodes and not the links data?

Comment: All you are missing is that "d" is not defined in your table mouse handlers. They should be passed in as arguments: .on("mouseover", function(d){...} The reason for this is that d3 will automatically pass the data associated with the moused-over element to the handler ... but you need a variable there to accept it! I'm not sure what browser you are testing in but look for how to show the "javascript console" in your browser of choice and you will see the error right away! In Chrome it is in the menu under View -> Developer -> Javascript Console.

Comment: Perfect - that worked!  When I mouseover a row, the corresponding circles are highlighted.  I tried to repeat the process for the reverse ... highlighting rows when I mouseover circles, but it didn't work.  See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVAdams/SDJjV/5/).  I defined a class for the table, `.attr("class", function(d) { return d.atom ;})`, and I added code to the mouseover, `d3.selectall("tr." + d.atom).style("background-color", "orange");`, but I've got something wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If the answer works perhaps you could accept it? You're logic for highlighting the table is correct - if you check the javascript console I think you will quickly see your error!

Comment: Ahh ... or should I say ahh.  Thank you so much for your help, @Superboggly!  It works in both directions now.  See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVAdams/SDJjV/6/).