# Mouseover in a scatterplot of a second svg in D3

Tags: d3.js, mouseover

I am trying to create a page with a scatterplot, a network diagram, and a table.  I was able to get the mousehandling to work on the network diagram and the table (with the help of @Superboggly at [Link D3 force layout network diagram with table on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308717/link-network-diagram-with-table-on-mouseover)).  Now I am trying to get the mousehandling to work on a second svg with a scatterplot, and I think I'm messing up the referencing.

```
var mapit = svg2.selectAll("maprect")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.long); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.lat); })
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("fill", "cyan")
    // This mouseover doesn't work, what am I missing?
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
        d3.select(this).select("rect").style("fill", "orange"); 
        })
    .on("mouseout",  function(d) { 
        d3.select(this).select("rect").style("fill", "cyan"); 
        });
```

I'm new to D3 and to JavaScript, and am confused by the collection of ... `mapit`, `svg2`, `maprect`, `graph.nodes`, `rect`, ... that I pieced together from other folks' examples.  Any suggestions?

The example is posted as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVAdams/bTHk2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close! Just remove the `.select("rect")` in the functions:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "orange"); 
    })
.on("mouseout",  function(d) { 
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "cyan"); 
    });
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTHk2/1/).

Comment: Excellent.  Can you explain why I need the `circle` in `d3.select(this).select("circle").style(...` for the network nodes but I don't need the `rect` in `d3.select(this).style(...` for the scatterplot squares?

Comment: The circles in the network live inside <g> elements, which is what the "this" refers to in that mouse event. If you do an inspect element on one of the nodes you should see it pretty clearly. The rectangles have no such parent. When in doubt, a "console.log(this)" inside an event function is always useful.